# Floated div's, max-width not working

Tags: html, css, radio-button, css-float

Forgive me, this is certainly a commonly asked question, and certainly a simple solution.  I am trying to turn a radio group into "nice buttons", I have it working 95% correctly, however I want the "buttons" to have a minimum and maximum width and size accordingly, I'm probably butchering that, but please look at the Fiddle below, I am trying to get the first "button"'s width to expand to accommodate the long content.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/charlesread/0bpvrcpj/6/][1]

```css
main {
  width: 800px;
  margin:auto;
}

div#radioContainer {
  text-align:center;
  margin: 10px;
}

div#radioContainer label {
  display:inline-block;
}
div#radioContainer label input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

div#radioContainer label input[type=radio] + div {
  width:100px;
  max-width:200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  float: left;
  position:relative;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

div#radioContainer label input[type=radio] + div p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div#radioContainer label input[type=radio]:checked + div {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div id="radioContainer">
<label><input type="radio" name="a"><div><p>One twothreefourfivesixseven</p></div></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="a"><div><p>One</p></div></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="a"><div><p>One</p></div></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<p></p>` tags. Instead use another div for the text. Check the css of the below snippet.

```css
main {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

div#radioContainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

div#radioContainer label {
  display: inline-block;
}

div#radioContainer label input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

div#radioContainer label input[type=radio]+div {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

div#radioContainer label input[type=radio]:checked+div {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.inner {
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="radioContainer">
    <label><input type="radio" name="a"><div><div class="inner">This is a very long text</div></div></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="a"><div><div class="inner">Thisisanotherlongtext...............</div></div></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="a"><div class="outer"><div class="inner">One</div></div></label>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Magnificent!  What a simple solution, would you mind providing an explanation as to why the simple change makes such a difference? Thank you so much!

Comment: @charlesread I don't know the exact reason but i have replaced the p tags with div because div takes as much space as you write content in it and that is what you want.

DIV is a generic block level container that can contain any other block or inline elements, including other DIV elements, whereas P is to wrap paragraphs (text).

DIV as a grouping element. You put elements in a DIV element so that you can set their alignments

Whereas "p" is simply to create a new paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this,
You can manually expand width with set a class to the specific Div.

```css
main {
  width: 800px;
  margin:auto;
}

div#radioContainer {
  text-align:center;
  margin: 10px;
}

div#radioContainer label {
  display:inline-block;
}
div#radioContainer label input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

div#radioContainer label input[type=radio] + div {
  width:100px;
  max-width:200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  float: left;
  position:relative;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

div#radioContainer label input[type=radio] + div p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div#radioContainer label input[type=radio]:checked + div {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

#radioContainer .expand{
width: 250px!important;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div id="radioContainer">
<label><input type="radio" name="a" ><div class="expand"><p>One twothreefourfivesixseven</p></div></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="a"><div><p>One</p></div></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="a"><div><p>One</p></div></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the content and the number of buttons will be dynamic, so I'd need them to adjust automatically.